# Minimum account balance required for 2 to travel to Zurich for 10 days

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-of-funds, zurich

I would like to know how much is the minimum balance to be maintained for myself and my husband for a stay of 10 days in Zurich. We hold Indian passport and are residing in Singapore. My husband hold PR in SG.
We have visa interview next week. I currently have 2500$ in my account. is it sufficient? We will be staying with my sis who is our sponsor for the trip and have her bank balance statements and payslips. 
Do we also bank account statement from bank or an estatement is fine?

Please provide us the details. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't your sister have a good idea of how much things cost in Zurich?

Comment: She says CHF 100 per day is enough. But just want to make sure so that there is no chance of rejection. Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about the balance required for a successful application for a Schengen visa? Or are you asking about how much money you might need to spend in Zurich during your stay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Visa policy of the Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Means_of_subsistence), the amount required for visitors to Switzerland is:

> CHF 100 per day; CHF 30 for students